# Panda dataframe: Select rows that are in a string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, select, filter

I have a dataframe as my dictionary contains a few tens of thousands of rows and 2 columns.

first column is id and the second one is an string.
input of my code is another string (usually a few thousand of words) and need to select rows if the input string contains that rows.
dataframe:

```
id  vals
1   apple
2   book
3   an apple
4   apple one
```

input string: this is an apple from apple one.

output must be something like this: 1,3,4
which are ids of included in input string.

I know how to do it by lists simply like this:

```
[key.id for key in keys if " "+(key.vals.lower())+" " in inputstring]
```

but we changed the dataflow and using dataframe instead. I need to do the same using indexing to make is as fast as possible

Comment: "usually a few thousand of words" seems like row-wise string search would be extremely slow for large datasets ... does this approach still make sense in that regard?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
input_string = "this is an apple from apple one"
list(df[[s in input_string for s in df['vals']]]['id'])
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 4]
```